# Intitialising an object of an interface as an argument of a method?

Tags: java, object, interface, actionlistener

As I am aware, you cannot make objects of interfaces, instead objects of classes that implement an interface, however, whilst looking at a tutorial on event handlers I found the following:

```
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
        tf.setText("Welcome to Javatpoint.");  
}  
});
```

First of all, I didn't know you could construct an object within the arguments of a method. Second, I know that ActionListener is an interface, so what exactly is the `new ActionListener` doing here? After reading around I get the vague idea that this is actually making a new class that implements `Action Listener`, but what is this class called? Can I make other objects of this class? And finally, how exactly is the above code any different from the following:

```
//where MyActionListener is a class that implements ActionListener

MyActionListener objectOfActionListener = new MyActionListener();
b.addActionListener(objectOfActionListener);

//and the method for actionPerformed is in the MyActionListener class
```

Comment: That's an anonymous class. It creates an unnamed class that implements ActionListener. Useful when something demands that you use a class that implements an interface, but you don't want the hassle of writing up a full named class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements the `ActionListener` interface.

You could of course create an explicit class of your own and instantiate it, but unless you need to reuse the same logic in more than one place, there's no big benefit in it.

Comment: Ah right, so is the object created here also an anonymous object? Does it exist only to act as an argument for the method?

Comment: @Psear In this case, ya. You could assign it to a variable of type ActionEvent to extend its life and use it elsewhere. It should also be noted that with the introduction of `FunctionalInterface`s, it isn't as necessary to use anonymous classes anymore. Your entire code snippet can just be replaced by a lambda that looks something like `(ActionEvent e) => { tf.setText("Welcome to Javatpoint."); }`.